# How can i extract specifict text from a string using indexof and substring?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this string and i used Substring but it's not what i wanted.
I want to remove the part in the string that start from index 39.
Then to remove another part start from another index.
And in the end to rebuild the string.

```
string test = "http://test.com/attachment.php?s=21c4a95ffd0c8110e18a44ace2468fb3&amp;attachmentid=85411&amp;d=1432094822";
test = test.Substring(39);
```

In the end the string should look like:

http://test.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=85411&d=1432094822

Comment: Are there any pattern for split your string? Is it always `39` character?

Comment: are you familiar with String.Split function or how to use RegEx.. also google msdn C# SubString function or `URI` Class I forgot about that one

Comment: you should use `System.Uri` to parse the URI.

Comment: You might want to look at [`string.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx).  It's like the inverse of `string.Substring`.  Though as @DanielA.White says `System.Uri` is the correct tool to use here.

Comment: First of all take a look at [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=VS.100).aspx) class. Since you're going to make few changes to the same string. StringBuilder is more efficient.

Comment: @sszarek I do not think that `StringBuilder` Class will fit for this particular scenario `URI` class has lots of useful methods that the OP can utilize to get the proper url parsing etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `System.Uri` to parse the URL instead to be safer.

```
var uri = new System.Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("http://test.com/attachment.php?s=21c4a95ffd0c8110e18a44ace2468fb3&amp;attachmentid=85411&amp;d=1432094822"));
var leftPart = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

var queryStringParts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(leftPart);
uriBuilder.Query = string.Format("attachmentid={0}&d={1}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryStringParts.Get("attachmentid")), 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryStringParts.Get("d")));

var result = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: You can remove the port by specifying `-1`, so `uriBuilder.Port = -1;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar approach to  Daniel's:

```
string finalurl = null;
string url = "http://test.com/attachment.php?s=21c4a95ffd0c8110e18a44ace2468fb3&amp;attachmentid=85411&amp;d=1432094822";
Uri uri;
if(Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    var queryString = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')).Split('#')[0];
    string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(queryString);
    var nameVals = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decoded);
    nameVals.Remove("s"); // remove your undesired parameter
    finalurl = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}?{4}"
            , uri.Scheme, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, uri.Authority, uri.AbsolutePath
            , nameVals.ToString());
}
```

You need to add a reference to the `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: why are you manually doing the query string?

Comment: @DanielA.White: because that was what came  into my mind. I have tested your approach after i've posted this but unfortunately it didn't work. Maybe i did something wrong. It says that `Query` is readonly.

Comment: yea that was a typo.

Comment: @DanielA.White: even if i like your approach it does not seem to give the desired result but: `http://test.com:80/attachment.php?d=1432094822`. So the port is not wanted and the `attachmentId` parameter missing.